# pg_search_scope: chaining scopes seems impossible

Tags: pg-search

I have a search form for searching "documents", that have a small dozen of search criterions, including "entire_text", "keywords" and "description".

I'm using `pg_search_scope`, but I have 2 different scopes.

This is in my document.rb:

```
pg_search_scope :search_entire_text, 
                :against => :entire_text, 
                :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                        :prefix => true,
                        :dictionary => "french"
                        }
                    }

pg_search_scope :search_keywords,
                :associated_against => {
                    :keywords => [:keyword]
                },
                :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                        :any_word => true
                    }
                }
```

Each separately works fine. But I can't do this:

```
@resultats = Document.search_keywords(params[:ch_document][:keywords]).search_entire_text(params[:ch_document][:entire_text])
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `pg_search_scope` but it looks like you indeed can't combine two `pg_search_scope`'s.

What you could do is use `:search_entire_text` with a `pg_search_scope` and use the resulting id's in a `Document.where([1,2,3])` that way you can use standard rails scope's for the remaining keyword searches.

Example:

```rb
# If pluck doesn't work you can also use map(&:id)
txt_res_ids = Document.search_entire_text(params[:ch_document][:entire_text]).pluck(:id)
final_results = Document.where(id: txt_res_ids).some_keyword_scope.all
```

Comment: pluck works actually. I used map, but pluck is easier.

Answer (score 0):

It works. Here's the entire code ... if ever this could help someone :

`Acte.rb` (I didn't translate to english, the explanations are commented to correspond to the question above)

```
pg_search_scope :cherche_texte_complet, #i.e. find entire text
                :against => :texte_complet, 
                :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                        :prefix => true,
                        :dictionary => "french"
                        }
                    }

pg_search_scope :cherche_mots_clefs, #find keywords
                :associated_against => {
                    :motclefs => [:motcle]
                },
                :using => {
                    :tsearch => {
                        :any_word => true
                    }
                }

def self.cherche_date(debut, fin) #find date between
    where("acte_date BETWEEN :date_debut AND :date_fin", {date_debut: debut, date_fin: fin})
end

def self.cherche_mots(mots)
    if mots.present? #the if ... else is necessary, see controller.rb
        cherche_mots_clefs(mots)
    else
        order("id DESC")
    end
end

def self.ids_texte_compl(ids)
    if ids.any?
        where("id = any (array #{ids})")
    else
        where("id IS NOT NULL")
    end
end
```

and `actes_controller.rb`

```
ids = Acte.cherche_texte_complet(params[:ch_acte][:texte_complet]).pluck(:id)

@resultats = Acte.cherche_date(params[:ch_acte][:date_debut],params[:ch_acte][:date_fin])
.ids_texte_compl(ids)
.cherche_mots(params[:ch_acte][:mots])
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

chaining works in pg_search 2.3.2 at least

```
SomeModel.pg_search_based_scope("abc").pg_search_based_scope("xyz")
```